# Why is Rick and Morty's dimension called "C-137"?

Tags: rick-and-morty

Rick and Morty is a show with multiple universes. They say that they come from "dimension C-137".

**Is there a special meaning to this name?**

Comment: I gave an answer below, but for the record: Dan Harmon has said on many occasions not to try to look for deeper meaning in most of the show. Kinda funny that the deeper meaning is that you shouldn't go looking for deeper meanings.

Comment: The fine structure constant in our universe is 1/137. It’s a ubiquitous and unitless constant that appears throughout physics. https://youtu.be/RCSSgxV9qNw     This is just speculation but C-137 might refer to Constant 137

Answer (score 14):

The only significance I could find is that **C-137** is **[Caesium-137](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium-137)**, a radioactive isotope that is also the most dangerous byproduct of a plutonium explosion.

This could be a coincidence, and the actual abbreviation for Caesium is Cs, and it has not been confirmed by official sources, and is merely a potential point of significance.

---

As for in-universe, canonical or officially confirmed significance, there is no mention of it in the show or otherwise, so until there is, it can only be pure fan speculation.

Comment: In-universe it’s just a random dimension, the main premise is that there are infinite dimensions, and the one we see in the show isn’t special in any way

Answer (score 5):

There has been no reason given for the name. Given the naming format, it stands to reason that all dimensions are labeled used a default naming scheme, rather than each dimension having a personalized name.

C-137 just happens to be "our" Rick's dimension. There is no significance to the number, it's just what it is.

Or, better answered in the words of Rick:

> Don't think about it.

Comment: I still don't see how you can be so sure there is no meaning to this number though

Comment: I still don't see how you can be so sure that there is. Do you have any proof that suggests otherwise? Because there is nothing mentioned about this in the R&M lore as far as I'm aware. My answer is based on the absence of any proof. Is it possible that future episodes might reveal a significance? Sure. But I highly doubt that this answer should be based on my skill at predicting the future.

Comment: Well in fact all I've got is a guy in reddit saying it could be a reference to Caesium-137 : https://www.reddit.com/r/rickandmorty/comments/3eabde/whats_so_special_about_dimension_c137/ctdg12p/?st=j4pphcd7&sh=16d6c9f6 but other than that I couldn't find anything, and I wonder if there is a scientific or pop-culture signification to this.

Comment: I know there is no in-universe reasons for now, I was wondering about a reference the creators could have done

Answer (score 2):

I have also seen the Cesium - 137 theory at a lot of places. But personally, I feel that the reference is simpler. 'c' is the speed of light and 137 as in the fine structure constant which equals '1/137'.

Comment: I'm just curious, how do these two constants relate to the show any more than other theories? Or to each other for that matter?

Comment: I think this is the right one. Fine-structure constant is a collection of constants. Like the speed of light etc. The value of it can be thought as "arbitrary" in the sense of 1/137 happens to be the value of this constant for a given universe. And this last part is what the Ricky and Morty multiverse thing is going about all the time https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Definition

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any canonical answer to the question other than the fact that they are from

> a universe designated 137, which falls along the *Central Finite Curve* (CFC), hence (possibly) C-137

I'm bordering dipping in to fan fiction/speculation here, but it seems implied that the CFC is a collection of universes which are in some way more stable/accessible/useful/similar. Anything said beyond that WOULD be fan fiction (such as implying that the first Ricks to travel interdimensionally just counted up as they went, starting with their own as C-1)

Comment: Canonically, the Finite Curve is the subset of universes in which Rick is the smartest person in the world.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there seems to be no official or a "Canon" explanation for any hidden meaning to the name "C-137"

However, regarding Caesium 137 (to quote from it's Wikipedia entry),

> "It is among the most problematic of the short-to-medium-lifetime
>   fission products because it easily moves..."

To me that seems appropriate to the in-show character of Rick. He's dangerous, reactive and mobile.

Also, if you take Yatharth's explanation regarding the fine structure constant, then you could take that as uniquely PHYSICALLY identifying the universe from which Rick C-137 originates (given how many fundamental physical constants, including "c", are related to it).

...seems to be making the point that Rick C137 is "Our Rick"...

OK, this is pure fan speculation but I think Dan Harmon's subconscious mind might have been working over time when he chose that name.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. It comes from the registry number on the side of the alliance search and rescue craft on the planet named Miranda in *Serenity*... the 2005 film that was based on the cult TV show *Firefly*. The creator of *Rick and Morty* is a big fan.

Don't believe me?  Watch the movie, pause it when Mal and crew find the crashed search and rescue ship on Miranda... clearly visible on side of ship is C 137 in futuristic script.

Comment: I do believe you, but if you could provide a screenshot (you can [edit] one into your answer), that would make for a greater post. A source for the creator being a fan of the show, as well :)

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the possibilities in the multiverse.

So C-137 would mean possibility 137 of the C Possibility, so it's a possibility inside a possibility, A-137 would have different origins of Rick and the possibilities of it, whereas C-136 would be very close to C-137.

For example, in the Citadel episode, the news reporters are from D-716. Even inside that there are many possibilities, so there are D-716, D-716 B, and D-716 C, and all three have different experiences as marked by their faces, but still such a close origin that they are all news reporters.

So according to this, when Rick and Morty ruined their dimension and came to this one, they were from a very nearby possibility, as they didn't skip a beat.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the community. Have you got any source material to support your answer ?

Answer (score -1):

My opinion is that's is the amount of dark energy in that universe. For example in our universe the amount is 0.000000000000000138 that is very close to 137 the Rick's universe. In the strings theory there are multiple universe, every universe has a different value and so different results based on this number. Take a look at this video:

Comment: Technically speaking, 0.000000000000000138 is only close to 137 if you move the decimal point waaaaaay over to the right. Also, where does the "C" come into it?

Comment: Constant 137? It's only a speculation and maybe they called 137 because it's easier than 0.000000000137

Comment: And I don't think it's the Cesium because exists others universe with different values like C-135 and 136

Comment: Could be C for Carbon the main building block of life here

Answer (score -3):

C 137 is a God designator.

C is the 3rd letter in the alphabet and so is given the value of 3

3 represents the holy trinity (father son holy spirit)
1 represents the one true God which is broken into the trinity

7 is the luckiest number in the universe and the gematria number of Christ if paired with another 7 (77)

Add up the c13 and you get 7. Pair it with the extra 7 and you have 77.

As our Rick is the Rickest of all, as well as a conscious immortal he will always be C137. In each universe he resides is a slight continuous branch off his own timeline he replaces their inferior identity with his own instead of impersonating them. He is the infinite Rick.

Beyond this all things have multiple meanings. Of course the shows creators know these things and believe them to be ultimately meaningless, a la the nihlistic nature of Rick and his universe.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Do you have any evidence that this is the correct interpretation? Have the creators commented on this?

Comment: There are no coincidences my friend.

Comment: still, we typically like to see actual evidence in our answers. pure speculation does not make a good answer, which is why questions are closed when they expressly call for it.

Comment: Then can you provide evidence that this is not a coincidence?

Comment: This is not a court of law. Any answer other than what the creators or writers give is pure speculation. As they have declined to give an answer there is no way to know why they designated our Rick C-137. The bible is encoded much in the same way I have laid out for you above. The names, the dates, the verses are all connected using alphanumerics. This is how I read into this. If his designator were B-180 it would not have any real value. As it is NOT some arbitrary set of letters and digits, rather a series of incredibly powerful code, one would surmise the creators knew what they were doing.

Comment: Hi @JoelX, SE is not a typical forum - answers are expected to cite sources, rather than personal conjecture. You may want to take the [tour].